# is it possible to convert this loop into a list comprehension in python

Tags: python, list, while-loop, list-comprehension

I have this small bit of `code` which I want to know if it could be written in `list comprehension`. The `while loop` part is what I am interested in condensing.

```
>>> sum=33
>>> final_list=[]
>>> LastCoin=[0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 
           1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1]
>>> while sum>0:
...    final_list.append(LastCoin[sum])
...    sum-=LastCoin[sum]
... 
>>> print final_list
[1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
>>>
```

Comment: The iteration pattern you're using is very irregular, it seems you're using the iterator as both an accumulator and an index. Could you give us some more context on the problem?

Comment: *possible* [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/248072)?

Comment: there is nothing to be gained from using a list comprehension here

Comment: The first step toward turning any `while` loop into a list comprehension is turning the `while` loop into a `for` loop. If there's no natural way to do that, then there won't be any natural way to turn it into a list comprehension. (There's always _some_ way to do it—worst-case, you could extract the loop into a generator function, then `final_list = [sum for sum in my_generator()]`… but that's hardly _useful_.)

Comment: I suppose it's worth mentioning that `sum` is the name of a built-in function, so you should choose some other name for your variable.

Comment: Another way to do this (that you probably don't want to do): The expression in a listcomp has to be in terms of nothing but constant values and the loop iteration value. You would _also_ need to include the last appended value. If you look at `functools.reduce` and `itertools.accumulate`, you can see that this is always possible. I can't think of any way to use that trick to make anything even remotely readable here, but maybe you can.

Comment: I dont know if this is even possible. thats the reason I posted for expert opinions

Comment: @abarnert, Thanks for notice about `reduce`, i using it in my answer.

Comment: @mhlester It was indeed a kind of XY problem: see the edit of my answer, please. I found a new solution when I stopped wanting to imperatively find one using a list comprehension.

Comment: @abarnert I'm kind of satisfied to have found a simpler, faster and above all more adapted solution than my first one. Take a look at my edit please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

#### Better solution

Not trying to use a list comprehension. Using recursion instead.
Simpler, and time of execution divided by 3 compared to my former solution.

```
LastCoin=[0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2,
          1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5,
          1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1]

def nekst(x,L,rec=None):
    if rec is None: rec = []
    rec.append(L[x])
    if x-L[x]>0: nekst(x-L[x],L,rec)
    return rec

print nekst(33,LastCoin)
```

result

```
[1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

#### Comparing execution times

NB: the following tests are done with recursive functions that haven't the line
`if rec is None: rec = []`.
The presence of this line increases a little (+12%) the execution time of the solution with a recursive function.

```
from time import clock

iterat = 10000
N = 100

LastCoin=[0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2,
          1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5,
          1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1]

counter = 33
te = clock()
for i in xrange(iterat):
    final_list = [LastCoin[reduce(lambda x, y: x - LastCoin[x],
                                   range(counter, i, -1))]
                   for i in range(counter -1, 0, -1)
                   if reduce(lambda x, y: x - LastCoin[x],
                             range(counter, i, -1))]
print clock()-te,'Omid Raha'

st=33
E1 = []
for n in xrange(N):
    te = clock()
    for i in xrange(iterat):
        susu2 = [st]
        susu2.extend(x for x in xrange(st,0,-1)
                     if x==(susu2[-1]-LastCoin[susu2[-1]]))
        fifi2 = [LastCoin[x] for x in susu2]
        del fifi2
    E1.append(clock()-te)
t1 = min(E1)
print t1,'eyquem 1'

E2 = []
for n in xrange(N):
    te = clock()
    for i in xrange(iterat):
        def nekst(x,L,rec):
            rec.append(L[x])
            if x-L[x]>0: nekst(x-L[x],L,rec)
            return rec
        fifi3 = nekst(st,LastCoin,[])
        del fifi3,nekst
    E2.append(clock()-te)
t2 = min(E2)
print t2,'eyquem 2, nekst redefined at each turn of the measurement loop'

def nekst(x,L,rec):
    rec.append(L[x])
    if x-L[x]>0: nekst(x-L[x],L,rec)
    return rec

E22 = []
for n in xrange(N):
    te = clock()
    for i in xrange(iterat):
        fifi3 = nekst(st,LastCoin,[])
        del fifi3
    E22.append(clock()-te)
t22 = min(E22)
print t22,'eyquem 2, nekst defined outside of the measurement loop'

W = []
for n in xrange(N):
    te = clock()
    for i in xrange(iterat):
        y = 33
        final_list=[]
        while y>0:
            final_list.append(LastCoin[y])
            y-=LastCoin[y]
        del final_list,y
    W.append(clock()-te)
tw = min(W)
print tw,'while-loop == %.1f %% of %s' % (100*min(W)/min(E22),min(E22))
```

result

```
4.10056836833 Omid Raha
0.29426393578 eyquem 1
0.114381576429 eyquem 2, nekst redefined at each turn of the measurement loop
0.107410299354 eyquem 2, nekst defined outside of the measurement loop
0.0820501882362 while-loop == 76.4 % of 0.107410299354
```

It's a little faster if the definition of the function `nekst()` is executed outside the timing loop.

.

### Original answer slightly edited

I couldn't do better than that:

```
sum=33
LastCoin=[0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2,
          1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5,
          1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1]

susu = [sum]
susu.extend(x for x in xrange(sum,0,-1)
            if x==(susu[-1]-LastCoin[susu[-1]]))
fifi = [LastCoin[x] for x in susu]

print 'susu  == %r\n'\
      'fifi  == %r\n'\
      'wanted : %r' % (susu,fifi,[1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5])
```

result

```
susu  == [33, 32, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10, 5]
fifi  == [1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
wanted : [1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

.

#### *The edit is*:

`x for x in xrange(sum,0,-1) if x==(susu[-1]-LastCoin[susu[-1]])`
*instead of original*
`x for x in xrange(sum,-1,-1) if x==(susu[-1]-LastCoin[susu[-1]])!=0`

Answer (score 5):

Is there any good reason you are trying to use a list comprehension?

I see personally a lot of people trying to wedge list comprehensions where they don't belong, because, you know, 'list comprehensions are faster - they're in native C! whereas your boring loop is in interpreted Python'. That's not always true.

Just as a reference, if we compare your original solution, which is concise and readable, against the two proposed answers, you may find your assumptions violated:

```
In [5]: %%timeit
   ...: sum=33
   ...: while sum > 0:
   ...:     final_list.append(LastCoin[sum])
   ...:     sum -= LastCoin[sum]
   ...:
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.96 µs per loop

In [6]: %%timeit
   ...: sum=33
   ...: susu = [sum]
   ...: susu.extend(x for x in xrange(sum,-1,-1)
   ...:             if x==(susu[-1]-LastCoin[susu[-1]])!=0)
   ...: fifi = [LastCoin[x] for x in susu]
   ...:
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.4 µs per loop
# 5x slower

In [10]: %timeit final_list = [LastCoin[reduce(lambda x, y: x - LastCoin[x], range(counter, i, -1))] for i in range(counter -1, 0, -1) if reduce(lambda x, y: x - LastCoin[x], range(counter, i, -1))]
10000 loops, best of 3: 128 µs per loop
# More than 60x slower!!
```

A list comprehension is a good choice if you are trying to do something for every element in a list - filtering (test every element for true/false), translation, etc. where the operation is separate for every element (and, theoretically, could often be parallelized). It's not very good at loops which do processing and change state during the loop, and they usually look ugly when you try. In this particular case, you only look at 8 items as you go through the list, because you are manually calculating indices to look at. In the list comprehension case, you would have to at least look at all 33.

I don't know if that's your motivation, but if it is, just leave it as a loop. Python loops aren't that bad after all!

Comment: I personally don't like to use ``timeit``, I never remind how to use it (I don't pretend it's a bad thing to use it). With my test using ``time.clock``, I didn't find a so big difference between execution times of my solution and the one of Omid Raha: just around 13 times longer to execute Omid's solution than my first mine, not 60 times. -- But I found another solution, see it please, it is 3 times faster, and simpler ! -- I upvote for your work of comparing execution times.

Comment: I use Ipython (ipython.org); in there, it's as simple as %timeit command. I never remember the arguments either, but i don't have to :)

Comment: I tested against your solution - it is simpler, but still not simpler than the original while loop. How could it be? It's the same algorithm, but with additional function calls. The time is still pretty fast, but about 70% slower in my testing - 1.66uS for the while loop, vs. 2.94uS for the recursive solution (my time was just `st=33; fifi3 = nekst(st, LastCoin, [])`, so I'd already refactored the function def out of the loop).

Comment: I've just given a look to IPython's site and it gave me the desire to learn about it and to use it. Seems very interesting. Thank you for the info. -- Something I would like to know: in which language is IPython implemented ? Is it based on C as Python itself, or in Python  or another else ?

Comment: i am not an IPython expert, but afaik it's (almost?) all pure Python. not 100% sure how the kernels work, and they are trying to extend it to integrate R, C++, etc. but everything i've looked it is just python code. Other cool simplifications are %prun (for profiling) and the ?/?? inspection features...

Comment: You are right, the while-loop solution is simple and the fastest one: I didn't think to test it but now I see its execution time is 60 % the execution time of my recursion solution with ``nekst`` defined outside the measurement loop (roughly equal to 1.66/2.94 == 0.56). The recursion solution is interesting when the same kind of process must be repeated several times in a code (that's the reason the functions exist !)

Comment: I don't know how I could obtain the ratio 60%. I did a more rigorous comparison of times and I obtain now that the execution time of a while-loop solution is only 80% of the execution time of my solution using a recursive function, not 60% as I said, sic. While your times give 56%. Sic. Timing is a difficult task to manage....

Comment: recursive functions are great sometimes. they're especially great for 'fractal' type algorithms, where you are processing a context, and the next context look just like this one but is bigger/smaller. it's not as good for linear-type algorithms, like this one. anyways, the point is not really that the while is much faster, but that it's definitely not slower, and also wins on clarity and conciseness.

Comment: _"processing a context, and the next context look just like this one but is bigger/smaller"_ : it appears to me that it's exactly the way my recursive function acts; it receives an index `x` and a list `L`, so it is somewhat equivalent to receiving the list (= context) `L[0:x+1]` and the next call of the function receives a smaller context since the next **x** to be passed is `x - L[x]` with the same `L`, resulting in a samller equivalent list `L[0:x-L[x]+]`.

Comment: I tend to prefer my recursive function because what it does is clearer for my mind. It gives me the impression to be a machinery that is feeded with an index and a list and it manages to skip from position to position in the list, keeping the elements at these positions, and knowing when to stop, and returning just the desired result without having to define a receiver list before the process. And the code block of the function is more immediately comprehensible at first glance than analyzing a while-loop, I don't why

Comment: I don't want to pretend that M-Y-Y solution is the be-e-est. I just mean that, considering that it is roughly as fast as a while-loop solution, and being somewhat more understandable for me, and it can be concisely reused as many times it is needed, it is a solution that has a valuable interest. -- By the way, in fact I was surprised to write this recursive function correctly at first writing , because I am not habitually very at ease with recursive functions.

Comment: sure, if you think in recursion, use it - totally agree with that. recursion does have some drawbacks, so i don't generally prefer it, but a good algorithm that's instantly understood is way better than a great algorithm that's incomprehensible anyways....

Comment: Well, thank you for your reflexions. I now think I have exhausted the subject. Have a good afternoon.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible:

```
counter = 33 # your sum variable
LastCoin = [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2,
            1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1]

final_list = [LastCoin[reduce(lambda x, y: x - LastCoin[x],
                              range(counter, i, -1))]

              for i in range(counter -1, 0, -1)

              if reduce(lambda x, y: x - LastCoin[x],
                        range(counter, i, -1))
              ]

print(final_list)
# [1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

But, it's not way of `import this` !

Comment: I hardly understand the process in your solution and it executes in a longer time than my solution as showed by Corley. Anyway it's an impressive solution, congratulations for this _"tour de force"_ -- You may be interested by my new solution in the edit of my answer

Comment: This would be a lot clearer if you didn't try to write it all in one 182-character-long line. Anyway, it looks like you're doing a reduce over the full range for every value, which makes it quadratic rather than linear, which explains why it's so slow. Many of the core devs like to say "inside every `reduce` is a loop crying to get out", and I don't always agree… but when there are _two_ loops crying to get out and flattened into one, that's a different story. Anyway, clever solution nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

I maybe a bit late to the party. With python 3.9, we can use walrus operator (:=)

If we use that, we can do the following and reduce the while statement to one line.

```
LastCoin=[0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2,
          1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5,
          1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1]

s = 33

final_list = [LastCoin[s]]
while (s:=s-LastCoin[s]) > 0: final_list.append(LastCoin[s])

print (final_list)
```

The output of this will be:

```
[1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```